# jQuery: Hide/Show divs based on an arbitrary number of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the [following code](https://jsfiddle.net/83pwbow3/).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="draft">Borrador</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="cancel">Cancelado</label>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="waiting" checked>Esperando</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="partially_available" checked>Parc. Disp.</label>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="confirmed" checked>Confirmado</label>
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="assigned" checked>Asignado</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="done">Hecho</label>
    </div>
</div>


<div state="draft">Div1</div>
<div state="done">Div2</div>
<div state="assigned">Div3</div>
<div state="assigned">Div4</div>
<div state="done">Div5</div>
```

Which contains a set of checkboxes, each checkbox has a certain initial state (checked/not checked) and a value. They can have assigned a name if needed.

The there is an arbitrary number of `<div>` which contain an attribute called `state` (which matches one of the checboxes).

- What shall be used in jQuery to make that each time user interacts with checkboxes corresponding `<div>`s are hidden or shown?
- What shall be used in jQuery to ensure that an intiial round is ran based on the checbox status to properly hide/show `<div>`s?

Thanks!,

Comment: *"What shall be used in jQuery to make that"* what do you mean by "that"? do you want to create those divs using jQuery?

Comment: @derloopkat I hope "that" has been properly used here. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/that Anyway for a further elaboration on the question you can check John's answer which addresses exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// Iterates over each checkbox on window load
$(window).on('load',()=>{
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(toggleDivs);
});

// binds an onchange handler to each checkbox
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',toggleDivs);

function toggleDivs(){
  // if its checked, show the div with the state equivelant to the checkbox's value
  if($(this).is(':checked')) $('div[state="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
  // otherwise hide it
  else  $('div[state="' + $(this).val() + '"]').hide();
}
```

> Note: this code is untested and may require some proofreading

Comment: Works like a charm, and it is clearly self-explained. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure -- glad to help!